# Is it possible to use Solr to query multiple, lucene and non-lucene indexes

Tags: solr

I'm wondering if it's possible to use Solr to query more than one index and combine the results.

The concrete problem is a web site based on various PDFs & DOCs as well as Notes documents. The Notes documents are user-restricted and should not appear in search results unless the user is authorised to view the document.

I think the simple docs could be searched for using Solr and Lucene and the Notes documents using Notes search.

Is there a way to extend Solr to search multiple indexes and merge the results?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that's possible. Sounds like that logic should be in the application layer. One  approach to consider would be to have a field in the schema which will indicate the type of document (like notes) or access level (public, private) then you could exclude them from the search results

`q=search+keywords&fq=-DocType:notes`

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm not a Notes specialist but I think the access control can be very fine and complicated. e.g. access by user or group membership. I cannot see how to put all that info into the index.